# Akka HTTP Request Time out Issue

Tags: postgresql, scala, akka-http

We have a use case to generate data according to the given time interval. With a single request, we are fetching the same data with different organizations.

While generating the data, there are lots of queries firing on the Postgres database i.e more than 70-80 and after processing the data, we return it.

Everything is implemented using Scala Futures. But it is giving time out so I have increased it to 5 minutes.

```
 post {
      pathPrefix("reporting") {
        path("data") {
          withRequestTimeout(300.seconds) {
           //code
     }
 } 

Response: [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(inbox-reporting)] Request timeout encountered for request [POST /reporting/data Strict(123 bytes)]
```

Even after having 5 minutes, it gives info request time out within 2-3 minutes of request and then there is no data returned. 300 time is also not a scalable solution as there will be much more data in production.

What should be the way to handle such large processing with the same date without time delay?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the request is timing out then the code is taking too long to produce the answer, so the problem is the database code rather than this HTTP code.

You need to put more detailed timing in your code to see why it is taking so long to process requests. This will help you to understand whether this is simply overload or a more specific issue with a particular class of requests.

I use code like this to wrap different parts of the code:

```
private var timeDepth = 0

def time[T](op: String)(code: => T)(implicit logger: Logger): T = {
  timeDepth += 1
  val pad = "\t"*timeDepth
  logger.info("{}Begin {}", pad, op)

  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val res = code
  val stop = System.currentTimeMillis()

  logger.info("{}{} took {}ms", pad, op, stop - start)
  timeDepth -= 1
  res
}
```

Usage:

```
  val result =
    time("Read from database") {
      //code
    }
```

If the problem is overload then you need to put in some rate pacing further upstream rather than wasting time on partially-fulfilling requests.

Comment: Yes, I knew that code is taking much time as they are lots of queries that get fired but it will take much time definitely. How can handle such scenarios without time out?
Thanks I will try this.